# Add css class using document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to add css class using javascript but its not working

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('oldclassname');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].className += 'newclassname';
}
```

but when I tried changing background it works

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("oldclassname");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

  x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong while adding css file

Comment: @alastair brown's answer is correct. You also have the option to avoid dealing with spaces in `className` by using [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Your code would then be `[i].classList.add('newclassname')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`className` is a *space separated* list of class names.  The problem with your code is that it doesn't separate the class names with spaces.  Try this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('oldclassname');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
{
   x[i].className += ' newclassname'; // WITH space added
}
```

Without the space, it has only one class name

```
<div class="oldclassnamenewclassname"></div>
//if use space
<div class="oldclassname newclassname"></div>//get two class name
```

Answer (score 5):

Better use `classList`:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('oldclassname');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].classList.add('newclassname');
}
```

```css
.newclassname { color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="oldclassname">Hello, world!</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi there is a much simpler way to do this using javascript

TO add a class: -

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('otherClassName')[0].classList.add('newClassName');
```

To remove a class:-

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('otherClassName')[0].classList.remove('newClassName');
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It works . Check your target class name formation.
Sample Code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.classFrom{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: red;
}

.classTo{
    font-family:cursive;
    color: blue;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function clickme(){
var elmList = document.getElementsByClassName('classFrom');
  for (i = 0; i < elmList.length; i++) 
    {
       elmList[i].className += " classTo";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="classFrom">SampleText</div>
<button onClick="clickme()">ChangeCSS</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This removes previous classes. This is clearly undesired because the question uses `+=`  instead of `=`.